Sorted order not reflected in excel while writing a sorted dataframe
In this Python program, I am reading an excel file and sorting the same based on a particular sort order defined in the program. I want to replace the contents original file with the sorted data. Although the excel is written with content, the data is not sorted!
I use pandas with openpyxl engine.
Upon investigation, it is seen that the dataframe is sorted. When I print the same in console, it gives the sorted result. However, after writing, the excel file does not reflect the sort.
Here is my code for the same:
        # Open the output workbook using openpyxl
        output_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(self.template_path), "test.xlsx")
        workbook = load_workbook(output_file_path)

        # Select the worksheet by name
        worksheet = workbook['Sheet1']

        # Load the output file into a DataFrame
        df = pd.read_excel(output_file_path, engine='openpyxl')

        # Load the output file into a DataFrame and sort it
        sort_order = ["D1", "D2", "R1", "W"]
        print(df.head())

        df.sort_values(by=["SortCol"], ascending=True, inplace=True, key=lambda x: pd.Categorical(x, categories=sort_order))
        print("Sort Order Result")
        print(df)
    # Overwrite sorted data in the existing worksheet
        for row, record in df.iterrows():
            for col, value in record.items():
                if row+2 >= 1 and column_mappings[col] >= 1: # added check to ensure row and column values are greater than or equal to 1
                    worksheet.cell(row=row+2, column=column_mappings[col]+1, value=value)
        
        # Save the changes
        workbook.save(output_file_path)


Delete your previous and run your code again, sometimes the previous file is not overwritten. Saving to .csv file instead of .xlsx may help as well.

Thank you for your response. I did try that as well. It did not work. However for my application, I want to edit the previous file than writing into a new file.

Sure, you need to provide a minimum working example for others to be able to help you.
